# How to rotate the device but change nothing in the view

Tags: ios, swift, rotation

I want the user to rotate the device but change nothing in the view (do not rotate the view 180 degrees). All I want is to println a sentence.

Here is my code yet - (it println the sentence but also rotate the device's view. In this example it was to the left but it does't really matter to what side):

```
override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
    if (UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation == UIDeviceOrientation.LandscapeLeft) {
        println("Device has been rotated.")
    }
    return true
}
```

Comment: It's really unclear what your asking.  Should the view rotate or not?  If not, why are you returning `true` to the question "Hey bud, should I rotate?"

Comment: @nhgrif Sorry for the misunderstanding. Let's say iv'e got a label in the middle of the view. when i rotate the device 180 degrees, I don't want the label to rotate, I only want to println the sentence to the console. How do I do it?

Comment: I don't care about the label.  The label isn't going to rotate unless you tell it to rotate.  It's not the label that's rotating.  A view controller is rotating its view.  If you turn the device 90 degrees to the left, should you also have to turn your head 90 degrees to the left to read the label (view did not rotate relative to the device) or should you be able to read it without turning your head (view did not rotate relative to your face)?

Comment: @nhgrif When I turn it 90 degrees I need to turn my head 90 degrees to read the label (and println the sentence).

Comment: Did you try changing `return true` to `return false`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
return true
```

to

```
return false
```